# occurred an ANRError by ANRWatchDog library but I don't get why it happens

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

This is the error log from [anrwatchdog](https://github.com/SalomonBrys/ANR-WatchDog)

```
com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError: Application Not Responding for at least 5000 ms.
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: main (state = RUNNABLE)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: AsyncTask #65 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1057)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: AsyncTask #67 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: AsyncTask #68 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: CleanupReference (state = WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:407)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:188)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:209)
    at xk.run(xk.java:2)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: ConnectivityManager (state = RUNNABLE)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: Crashlytics Exception Handler1 (state = WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:64)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:324)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.park(CoroutineScheduler.java:795)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.tryPark(CoroutineScheduler.java:740)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.java:711)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.java:665)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-10 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-11 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-2 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-4 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-5 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-6 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 5 more
10:22
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-7 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-8 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: DefaultDispatcher-worker-9 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: FinalizerDaemon (state = WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:407)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:188)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:209)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:204)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon (state = WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.sleepUntilNeeded(Daemons.java:269)
    at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:249)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: FrameMetricsAggregator (state = RUNNABLE)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: GmsDynamite (state = WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at cy.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamiteloader@213016048@21.30.16 (040400-0):2)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: GoogleApiHandler (state = RUNNABLE)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: HeapTaskDaemon (state = BLOCKED)
    at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.runHeapTasks(VMRuntime.java)
    at java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run(Daemons.java:433)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: InputConnectionHandlerThread (state = RUNNABLE)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: JavaBridge (state = RUNNABLE)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: Measurement Worker (state = RUNNABLE)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecute(SQLiteConnection.java)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.execute(SQLiteConnection.java:555)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransactionUnchecked(SQLiteSession.java:437)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.endTransaction(SQLiteSession.java:401)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.endTransaction(SQLiteDatabase.java:524)
    at hx.q(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@213016048@21.30.16 (040400-0):12)
    at jy.T(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@213016048@21.30.16 (040400-0):85)
    at jy.D(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@213016048@21.30.16 (040400-0):2)
    at kl.B(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@213016048@21.30.16 (040400-0):16)
    at kg.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@213016048@21.30.16 (040400-0):0)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at in.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_measurementdynamite@213016048@21.30.16 (040400-0):5)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: OkHttp ConnectionPool (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool.performCleanup(ConnectionPool.java:307)
    at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool.runCleanupUntilPoolIsEmpty(ConnectionPool.java:244)
    at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool.-wrap0(ConnectionPool.java)
    at com.android.okhttp.ConnectionPool$1.run(ConnectionPool.java:98)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: OkHttp https://env.example.info/... (state = WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at okhttp3.internal.Util.wait(Util.java:545)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.waitForIo$okhttp(Http2Stream.java:716)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.java:140)
    at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2ExchangeCodec.readResponseHeaders(Http2ExchangeCodec.java:96)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.Exchange.readResponseHeaders(Exchange.java:106)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:79)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:34)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:95)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:83)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:76)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:109)
    at okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor.intercept(HttpLoggingInterceptor.java:154)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:109)
    at com.example.repository.remote.ServiceGenerator$createService$$inlined$-addInterceptor$1.intercept(ServiceGenerator.java:1084)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.java:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.java:517)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: Okio Watchdog (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout.awaitTimeout(AsyncTimeout.java:311)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout.-wrap0(AsyncTimeout.java)
    at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$Watchdog.run(AsyncTimeout.java:286)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: PlatformServiceBridgeHandlerThread (state = RUNNABLE)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
    at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: ReferenceQueueDaemon (state = WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:150)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: RxCachedWorkerPoolEvictor-1 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1103)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:1084)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: RxSchedulerPurge-1 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: ScionFrontendApi (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1057)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: StethoListener-main (state = RUNNABLE)
    at libcore.io.Posix.accept(Posix.java)
    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.accept(BlockGuardOs.java:64)
    at android.system.Os.accept(Os.java:43)
    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.accept(LocalSocketImpl.java:336)
    at android.net.LocalServerSocket.accept(LocalServerSocket.java:90)
    at com.facebook.stetho.server.LocalSocketServer.listenOnAddress(LocalSocketServer.java:85)
    at com.facebook.stetho.server.LocalSocketServer.run(LocalSocketServer.java:74)
    at com.facebook.stetho.server.ServerManager$1.run(ServerManager.java:40)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: TcmReceiver (state = RUNNABLE)
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.readba_native(LocalSocketImpl.java)
    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl.-wrap1(LocalSocketImpl.java)
    at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketInputStream.read(LocalSocketImpl.java:110)
    at com.qti.tcmclient.DpmTcmClient$TcmReceiver.run(DpmTcmClient.java:140)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: arch_disk_io_0 (state = WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: arch_disk_io_1 (state = WAITING)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: arch_disk_io_2 (state = WAITING)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: arch_disk_io_3 (state = WAITING)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: awaitEvenIfOnMainThread task continuation executor1 (state = WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:413)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1058)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:64)
    at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.internal.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:27)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: com.google.firebase.crashlytics.startup1 (state = WAITING)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: firebase-installations-executor-39 (state = TIMED_WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:201)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2077)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:438)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1057)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1118)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: firebase-installations-executor-40 (state = RUNNABLE)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: glide-active-resources (state = WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:407)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:188)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:209)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources.cleanReferenceQueue(ActiveResources.java:128)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources$2.run(ActiveResources.java:61)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ActiveResources$1$1.run(ActiveResources.java:43)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.github.anrwatchdog.ANRError$$$_Thread: glide-animation-thread-0 (state = WAITING)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java)
    at java.lang.Thread.parkFor$(Thread.java:2127)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:161)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2035)
at java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue.take(PriorityBlockingQueue.java:519)
    at java.util
```